# How to pause a video in accordion in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video library  in my project. So when the accordion  closes the video should  pause. I tried the inbuilt function  of  library as well as external  function but the problem  persists. Any idea how to resolve  it.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: It is company  project  so I won't be  able to  share that. Even a rough idea about the problem will help.